# Cordova camera plugin not working on windows 8.1 phone

Tags: cordova, camera, windows-phone-8.1

Cordova, Windows Platform 5.0.0 (the latest), Nokia Lumia 635.

Taking a photo is flaky at best. Sometimes it works, albeit very slowly, but mostly the camera seems to freeze then (eventually) the app crashes.

The last error message I got was:

> Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

The phone has over 3GB of available space and there are very few apps running in the background.

The app has recently been upgraded from the WP8 platform (now deprecated) to the Windows Platform.  Previously there were no issues with the camera.

Our client uses the Nokia Lumia 635 so the app has to work.  I'm at dead end at the moment, we can't revert to WP8 as we also need to support Windows 10 phones.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onAddPhotoSuccess, onAddPhotoFail, {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
});
```

Comment: Is this Windows Phone 8.1 or Windows Phone 8.1 Update 2? WP 8.1 w/o upd 2 has memory leak issues on some devices. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues/55

Comment: Software: Windows Phone 8.1 update.  OS version: 8.10.14234.375.  Is this update 2?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The phone is not on update 2 and update 2 was not widely released for all devices, it looks like the 635 did not receive this update. Game over.

Comment: What you could try - is to reduce the camera image resolution like that https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/commit/89a9c69f6d2ba2d0e3d5ae25d937d3772c48b67c